# Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions: how to arrive at the result naturally?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, analytic-number-theory

I've seen the following theorem proved several times in several different ways:

> Let $a, b$ be relatively prime.  There are infinitely many prime numbers in the sequence $a,a+b,a+2b, ...$

The most difficult part of the argument comes down to showing that if $\chi$ is a nontrivial Dirichlet character, then $L(s,\chi)$ does not vanish at $s = 1$.

I have understood the individual details of the arguments.  But I have never felt like I really understand why the result is true.

Suppose you temporarily forgot what you knew about $L$-functions, Dirichlet density, Fourier analysis etc.  You know basic number theory and complex analysis.  How would you go about thinking about this problem in such a way as to naturally arrive at the result?  If necessary, you can rediscover L-functions as part of the process, but please justify your discovery with intuition.

Comment: Natural is to use analytic methods. In fact, an $L$-function is natural for studying primes, e.g., the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Selberg published [an "elementary" proof](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969454?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), but I doubt that will meet your requirements.

Comment: Reinvent L-functions. There are a few special cases you can handle using tricks involving polynomials but already for primes congruent to $2 \bmod 5$ I think there is no hope.

Comment: The best way to think to it is the proof you learnt : $L(s,\chi) = \prod_p (1-\chi(p)p^{-s})^{-1}$. For $Re(s) > 1/2$ :  $\log L(s,\chi) = \sum_p \chi(p) p^{-s}+  O(1)$ so that $\sum_{\chi \bmod b} \chi(a)\log L(s,\chi) = \phi(b) \sum_{p \equiv a \bmod b} p^{-s} + O(1)$, and it reduces to show the last series diverges for some $Re(s) > 1/2$.

Comment: What is the precise meaning of $\log L(s,\chi) = \sum_p \chi(p)p^{-s} + O(1)$?  I'm familiar with big O notation for functions of a real domain, but not complex.

Comment: 3 years old, but very interesting question, just looking into this myself, I disagree on the fact that analytic methods are the natural approach. Although complex analysis is very powerful, at its core it is mysterious, and it does not generalize well (to say for example Dickson's conjecture). I believe that ”elementary proofs” of such theorems " can provide new levels of insight and further reveal the beauty of number theory ".

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but I wager you'll find it interesting anyway. Consider the statements:

> (*Strong Dirichlet*) For each $m>0$ and each $a$ relatively prime to $m$, there exist **infinitely many primes** $p \equiv a \pmod m$.
>
> (*Weak Dirichlet*) For each $m>0$ and each $a$ relatively prime to $m$, there exists **at least one prime** $p \equiv a \pmod m$.

While the statement *WD* might look a lot weaker at first glance, we have the very elementary

> **Theorem**. *Strong Dirichlet* is equivalent to *Weak Dirichlet*.
>
> *Proof*. It is clear that *SD* implies *WD*.
>
> Suppose on the other hand that *WD* holds, but not *SD*. We will
> derive a contradiction, which will show that *WD* implies *SD*.
>
> If *WD* holds, but not *SD*, then there exists an $M$ and an $A$ such
> that  $(M, A)=1$ and there are **finitely many primes** $p \equiv A \pmod M$; let $S$ be the set of these primes. Let $q>M$ be a prime
> large enough such that there exists a congruence class $B\not\equiv 0 \pmod q$
> different from all elements of $S \pmod q$. Then, the simultaneous
> congruences
>
> $$p \equiv A \pmod M$$ $$p \equiv B \pmod q$$
>
> have no solution $p$ prime: the first imposes that $p \in S$, and the
> second rules it out. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, these equations
> are equivalent to an equation of the form
>
> $$p \equiv C \pmod{qM}$$
>
> with $(C, qM)=1$, which has no solution; but this contradicts our
> assumption *WD*. Therefore *WD* implies *SD*.

So, modulo this elementary argument, it's just as hard to prove that there are infinitely many primes $p \equiv a \pmod m$ for any $(a,m)=1$ than it is to prove that there is always at least one such prime.

Is it easier to believe *WD* than *SD*? Personally I don't think so - what's left to believe anyways once you've internalised Dirichlet's proof?

Comment: That can be proved in a more direct way too, avoiding an argument by contradiction.  Suppose $(a,m) = 1$ and we have primes $p_1, \ldots, p_r \equiv a \bmod m$. We may assume $1 \leq a \leq m-1$.  (The case $m=1$ is trivial.) There is $k \geq 1$ such that $m^k > p_i$ for $i = 1,\ldots,r$. The congruence $p \equiv a + m^k \bmod m^{k+1}$ has a prime solution by WD, and from $0 < a + m^k < m^{k+1}$ we have $p \geq a+m^k > p_i$ for all $i$, so $p$ is not any of the $p_i$ and obviously $p \equiv a \bmod m$.